# GWT offline, load json data in html

Tags: javascript, html, json, gwt

i got the following scenario. Im using GWT as an offline application. i stored my data as json in a js file and im including this js file in the html page of the GWT application. Im getting the included json data via jsni methods.

my Problem is, that when i use this offline (file://), the application has a very long startup time (ca 10 seconds at ~ 5mb json data file).
Interesing is, that when i put my application to a webserver and access my application there (http://), it loads without any loading time.

is there a difference in the file / http protocol when loading html files which include js files?

Is there a better way to use gwt offline with data?

Comment: Have you had a look at the network debugger of your browser's debugger? What causes the long loading time should be visible there.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is static and is always needed in your app, you can use a [TextResource](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#TextResource) instead of wrapping it in a JS file.